# Merging free space of hard drive to primary partition

Tags: partitioning

I have purchased a new HDD, I tried to format making 1 primary partition, I converted the rest unallocated space to extended partition then to logical drive now I have 3 logical drives.

I feel that the size allocated to the primary partition is less so I used shrink option to the 3 logical partitions in `diskmgmt` but each partition is resulting in one memory block of Free space. Now I want to merge these free spaces to my primary partition.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the screenshot from Disk Management?

Answer (score 0):

At least the concept of the answer seems simple, create a liveCD to use a freeware partition tool like > http://partedmagic.com/doku.php < or some other. -EaseUS ?

Comment: I used this file and merged some space in C drive and result?? It deleted all the boot information and I had to reformat my system. I tried twice and reformatted twice. Not a good option.